# is it possible to Add Multiple Scenarios in Test Plan Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, test-plan

I have 100 virtual users, and 3 script. I need to assign 20 users to 1 script, 30 users to 2nd script and 50 users to 3rd script  …

Questions:

1. How to Add 3 Scenarios(Scripts) to single Test Plan?
2. How to assign load Distribution to 3 scripts (assign 20 users to 1 script, 30 users to 2nd script and 50 users to 3rd script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to use your scripts (read the doc and use [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) in included scripts)

To assign load distribution just use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and use percentage for example to distribute load accross all users.

Each Throughput Controller will contain the Include Controller for 1 script.